# how to re-order IDs after deleting a row in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm using C# to make program that has a sql database, in the database I have a table named `Workers`, it has an auto increament and Primary key `ID_column`, when I delete a record the IDs will have a gap between each other.

What should I do re-order the IDs after deleting a record?

UPDATE

What I am going to do is to display the record on the screen after finding it,
so I tried to do that using the `ID` but it make some exception because of these gaps!!

UPDATE 2

This is the code I tried to use

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchFor = "";
        string searchOn = "";
        string searchString = "";
        int results = 0;

        if (searchTextBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to search for");

        if (cb1.Text == "Last Name")
        {
            searchFor = searchTextBox.Text.Trim();
            searchOn = "last_Name=";
            searchString = searchOn + "'" + searchFor + "'";
        }

        if (cb1.Text == "Job Title")
        {
            searchFor = searchTextBox.Text.Trim();
            searchOn = "job_Title=";
            searchString = searchOn + "'" + searchFor + "'";
        }

        DataRow[] returnedRows;

        returnedRows = ds1.Tables["Workers"].Select(searchString);

        results = returnedRows.Length;

        if (results > 0)
        {
            DataRow dr1;

            dr1 = returnedRows[0];
            inc = (int)dr1["Worker_ID"]-1;

            NavigateRecords();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No such Record");
        }

    }
```

`inc` is the currently displayed record and `NavigateRecords()` is do display the record with the giving number `inc`

```
void NavigateRecords()
    {
        DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Workers"].Rows[inc];

        textBox1.Text =  dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        textBox2.Text =  dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        textBox3.Text =  dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to?  Most systems don't bother because there is no reason to.

Comment: if I deleted the 5th record then it will be 1,2,3,4,6,7 ...

Comment: I want to use the ID in my code to find some records

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I suspect there is a much better solution to your problem.

Comment: guys you mean I don't have to ???

Comment: The primary key columns is not (and should not be) used for ordering or any other busines logic. It has only one purpose: it's the identifier. There's no reason to fill the "gaps".

Comment: No you don't have to reshuffle your id. Imagine if your ID is used as foreign key by other tables. What do you plan to do, adjust the IDs in these other tables?. What if your table has millions of record and you decide to delete the one with ID=1?

Comment: The fact that these `ID` values *happen* to be numeric, and (before deletion) have no "gaps" are purely an artifact of how they're automatically generated for you. So far as possible, you should treat these `ID` values as opaque blobs - with no inherent meaning.

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to display the ID on screen. If you're getting an error, please post the relevant code and stack trace.

Comment: thanks guys ... I got the message, I will try to do it with other way

Comment: @firas man, just don't assume that they are sequential (e.g. don't use +1/-1 when moving through rows...)

Comment: @firasman: Your last update is a completely different question and you should really ask another question. Add also the code you've used to diplay the current/deleted record.

Comment: UPDATE 2 ... what i want to do @Tim Schmelter

Comment: @firasman: I've recommended to ask **another** question not to edit this since now all available answers are wrong and your title is not related to your actual question. Instead you should have accepted Marcs answer and created a new question.

Comment: Ok I got it ... i added the code just to show you what I want to do, Thank you

Comment: @firasman Did you solve your problem? A feedback would be appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Normally, we never change an ID in a database for integrity reason.

In your case, I recommend using the [Row_Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) if it's for a display reason

There's no problem having gaps in a database.

Answer (score 4):

When people die, do they "re-order" their SSN?

Don't do anything, don't reorder it.

Just imagine the trouble you'd get if you have a million workers, and a billion orders related to this works. Now, delete Worker no 1. You'd have to re-order not just the million worker records IDs, but also the the billion order records that references the worker's ID.

The exception you are having is probably not because of the "missing" ID.

Can you post the code that is throwing the exception and the exception itself?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't re-order IDs, because other tables may have reference for this ID.
If the ID is changeable, therefore insignificant in any way, you can just delete this column all together.

Answer (score 1):

You want to reset the seed value of identity column:

There is possibility to reseed the value of the identity column

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('Customer', RESEED, value)
```

Please check out this link too

http://geekswithblogs.net/TakeNote/archive/2007/11/30/117258.aspx